# Prometheus Union of Ranged Vectors

Tags: monitoring, metrics, grafana, prometheus

I have two range vectors (# of hits and misses) that I want to aggregate by their types. Some of the types have hits, other misses, some with both. These are two independant metrics that I'm trying to get a union of but the resulting vector doesn't make sense. It's missing some of the values and I think it's because they have either all hits or misses. Am I doing this completely the wrong way?

```
sum by (type) (increase(metric_hit{}[24h]) + sum by (type) (increase(metric_miss{}[24h])
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off, it's recommended to always initialise all your potential label values to avoid this sort of issue.

This can be handled with the `or` operator:

```
sum by (type) (
     (increase(metric_hit[1d]) or metric_miss * 0)
  + 
     (increase(metric_miss[1d]) or metric_hit * 0)
)
```

Comment: Good advice on qualifying down by labels. I always do but I omitted it in this example for simplicity. I tried something very similar to this by or-ing either the ranged vectors or increased functions directly. Can you explain why/how this is working? I'm guessing it has to do something with missing data-points in the aggregation and if so you're taking the only available data-point from the joined vector and just plotting a 0 from it -- am I correct?

Comment: You can or them directly, but that's not the same as adding them. To add them you need to get the same set of labelsets on both sides.